# Board structure relative to ground plane

Tags: pcb-design

I'm sorry if this question has already been asked, but I did not reach a full understanding of this subject area.I have read several guides for PCB layout, including the articles on this site. And now I want to consult with you to make sure that everyone understood correctly.

I plan to design pcb that will have onboard set of components. I'm worried about the performance of the pcb, since the board based on STM32 microcontroller will communicate with digital IMU ( MPU-9250 6 dof accelerometer + gyroscope ), drive BLDC using MOSFETs and measure set of ADC signals ( back-emf ) as feedback from BLDC.

Based on this explanation: http://sa.nxp-lpc.com/docs/an10897.pdf
Here is picture:
[image]

I plan to use 3 ground plane with ground plane bridges to pass signals:
[image]

**Digital GND** above which I will place Microcontroller and IMU IC which will communicate using I2C protocol.

**Power GND** above which I will place voltage regulator and set of MOSFET to drive 3-phase BLDC. That MOSFETs will be driven by MCU's PWM signals.

**Analog GND** that will receive back EMF from BLDC and pass them to MCU's voltage comparators.

1) Does this structure is correct? Or it is completely wrong?

STM32 has onboard ADC and voltage comparator.

2) If I have to use them did I should consider MCU as a mixed signals IC? And accordingly place a MCU between digital and analog ground as here:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a very wide ranging question and I am going to answer only one part.

Because an ADC has to contain analogue and digital sections it needs to sit across the boundary between analogue and digital ground planes. This is a generalism and there will likely be exceptions to this rule.

Comment: Andy aka, there is no ADC IC in use, I will use microcontroller ( MCU ) to measure analog signals. Should I place it in same manner (as ADC, between analog and digital ground planes ) ?

Comment: The internal ADCs are no different. That part of the chip should straddle the boundary with care to ensure decouplers are grounded on the correct part of the ground plane.

Comment: So, used MCU chip has 3 pair of VCC & VSS pins that should be connected to Digital GND and 1 pair of AVCC & AVSS that should be connected to Analog GND?

Comment: Yes and possibly isolate HF currents with inductors - read the data sheet to see what it specifically says - it should say something useful in this area.